# Can you set Apache's DocumentRoot relative to the conf file?

Tags: apache, apache2, httpd.conf

When setting up an apache2 virtual host, is it possible to reference the path of the `.conf` file within the `.conf` file?

If I have a directory structure like:

```
root/conf/vhost.conf
root/log/error.log
root/public/
```

Can I do something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...

  DocumentRoot ${THIS_CONF_FILE_PATH}/../public
  ErrorLog  ${THIS_CONF_FILE_PATH}/../log/error.log

  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do something like that, but to keep things simple you should set the ServerRoot directive to your root dir. For example, something like this would look much cleaner:

```
ServerRoot /path/to/root    
Include conf/*.conf
...
```

Than your vhost.conf file could look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...

  DocumentRoot public
  ErrorLog log/error.log

  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I should back up a bit and mention that I'm trying to achieve something like:

    vhost1/conf/vhost.conf
    vhost1/log/error.log
    vhost1/public/

    vhost2/conf/vhost.conf
    vhost3/log/error.log
    vhost4/public/

I believe ServerRoot can only be set once, which doesn't really allow me to do what I was planning. Definitely useful being reminded that I'm doing something unorthodox though.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish. I believe you should be able to use syntax like this to include config files Include */conf/*.conf, but I don't see any issues with hard-coding virtual hosts DocumentRoot and Error paths. You will have to do the same thing with the ServerName and ServerAlias directives, so why not just reuse the strings.